# Permission Error with WSGI while Setting up Apache with Django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/path/.virtualenvs/django_project/bin/activate_this.py'
```

Recently I am trying to get django to work with apache through wsgi.

After setting all the configurations, I ran into the above problem. Does anyone here has any idea on how the permission error can be resolved? In fact i m using 755 permission mask on that file.

Here is the wsgi file

```
import os
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/path/.virtualenvs/django_project/bin/activate_this.py")
exec(open(activate_this).read())
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Have you tried checking file context, if you have SELinux it may be restricting and causing the Permission Error